# What is the difference between React, Ember, Angular, and Polymer libraries?

Tags: javascript

I'm a designer trying to learn js. I have (kinda) master HTML5 and CSS3 and moving onto Javascript. After much research, I see most people suggesting learning react, ember, angular, or polymer.

What are the difference between these and which framework or library should I learn if I want to build my own SaaS program?

Comment: Unfortunately, opinion based questions are not permitted on StackOverflow. Oh, and the answer of course is "it depends". :-P

Comment: this is a question that would be *very difficult* to answer in this format.  You are unlikely to find anyone who has worked with every one of these frameworks extensively enough to give objective comparisons;  instead, you would certainly find answers which are colored by the framework of the answerer preference.  you are welcome to join the Chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript, which is better geared for discussion, but be prepared for bias there as well.

Comment: What GregL said. And also: PLEASE learn JavaScript before learning any JavaScript frameworks. Really. If not, you'll never fully comprehend what frameworks are doing behind the scenes. Then, learn jQuery. Because you're sure to encounter it in existing code. Finally, pick libraries (and maybe something that compiles to JavaScript, like TypeScript, CoffeeScript or Dart) depending on what you're building.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a significant question where the answer really depends on what you want to do.

Here is a short discussion on the difference between React and Ember [HERE](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-key-differences-between-Ember-js-and-React-js)

In short, Ember is an opinionated framework where Reach is more of a front end 'view' where you have options for your back end.

Similar to the differences between React and Ember, Angular is a complete framework for building apps, Polymer is a library for creating components.

Picking the right tool for the job depends on a number of things, such as your experience with coding languages, resources for front and back end development, security concerns, performance, how your SaaS will be deployed, etc...

I recommend creating a  set of requirements that your SaaS will have, then looking into each of the framework options to help determine which is the right tool for you. You should look into learning ES6, there are lots of free tutorials. ES6 is becoming more Python like and easier to use--more readable.

They are all good options. My preference is a Python (like django) back end with a React front end. The React components you build can be used with React-Native to build mobile apps for Android, iOS, and (yes, really) Windows 10 UWP apps.

There is a learning curve for all of these, hours of fun.